# Why I can't share audio files in React Native?

Tags: react-native, mp3, share

I'm trying to make a button that gives me the possibility to share an mp3 file in another app(for example WhatsApp, telegram and others). I used react-native-share ( from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share and from react), but it seems it doesn't work with mp3 files. I tried to force it by using 'type: "audio/mp3",' and it doesn't work too. Every time the share menu opens, and then it tells me "sorry this type of file is not yet supported". So how can I fix it? There's a way to force it, or maybe I need to use another library or there's not away? Here's my code:

```
import { Share } from 'react-native-share';
```

inside render function there is the two function that I tried:

```
const shareaudio = async () => {
  Share.share({
    url: 'file://android/app/src/main/res/raw/dontgetmewrong',
    type: "audio/mp3",
  })
};


const shareSingleImage = async () => {
  const shareOptions = {
    title: 'Condividi',
    url: audio.audio1,
    failOnCancel: false,
    type: "audio/mp3",
  };
  try{
    const ShareResponse = await Share.open(shareOptions);
    setResult(JSON.stringify(ShareResponse, null, 2));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error =>', error);
    setResult('error: '.concat(getErrorString(error)));
  }
};
```

And here are my two buttons for my two fucntions

```
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={shareSingleImage}>
          <Text>Share</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={shareaudio}>
          <Text>Share</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: please help me, I try making it works, but I can't DD:

Comment: Have you find any particular solution for sharing audio?

Comment: look at the answer chaurasia gave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this link file://android/app/src/main/res/raw/dontgetmewrong
is convert into Decode from Base64 format.

with the help of this site https://www.base64decode.org/

then,

url: 'Decode from Base64 format'